# Non-breaking space between span content and text

Tags: html, css

Can I make a non-breaking space between `span` content and text? I read about it, but don't see same situation.

```
<span style="some_style">
    <span number="1">1</span>"Some big text"
</span>
```

I need to add a non-breaking space between `span` content (`number="1"`) and the first word after it only.

Thank you

[image][image]

Comment: "non-breaking space" means?

Comment: not break by line, it can be span content  in one line and text in other, but i need span content (number) have always  near first word of text, without break by line

Comment: I'm unable to understand non-breaking space. do you mean float? margin? padding? can you provide a simple sketch for it.

Comment: @user3546748 It is already in single line. Check http://jsfiddle.net/yczs7qtp/

Comment: if you have <span number="1">1</span>"Some big text" and you will increase font size, it can be : "1+"newline"+"Some big text"",  i need have "1Some" +"new line"+ "big text"", there is &nbsp; for text, but can't make in this case

Comment: You aren't by chance trying to make an `<OL>` ([Ordered list (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)), are you?

Comment: i added screenshot, as you can see number 5 is one line and text is in other one, but now i think that it is css problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On seeing your example image, I'm not sure that what you are asking for is actually what you need.

I suspect that the 'number' span should actually be **outside** the containing block which would usually involve absolute positioning.

Like so.

```css
.some_style {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: justify;
}
span[number] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<span class="some_style">
    <span number="1">1</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est incidunt ducimus facilis quae magnam vel sit alias consequatur voluptate modi repellat enim eaque soluta accusantium.
</span>

<span class="some_style">
    <span number="2">2</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est incidunt ducimus facilis quae magnam vel sit alias consequatur voluptate modi repellat enim eaque soluta accusantium.
</span>
```

In fact, using `data-attributes`, you can do this without the internal span entirely.

```css
.some_style {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: justify;
}
.some_style:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-number);
  top: 0;
  left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<span class="some_style" data-number="1"> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est incidunt ducimus facilis quae magnam vel sit alias consequatur voluptate modi repellat enim eaque soluta accusantium.
</span>

<span class="some_style" data-number="2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est incidunt ducimus facilis quae magnam vel sit alias consequatur voluptate modi repellat enim eaque soluta accusantium.
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want super script!
Use the `<sup>` tag to do this.
The sup tag makes it go up and become smaller.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yczs7qtp/4/
Hope it works!

Comment: I think: The superscript isn't the problem. The problem is that the superscribed number could be at the end of a line and, if that happens, the line should be broken before the number so the number would stay with the following word.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want is that lines can't break between the numbers and the following words.

How you have it in the snippet works for me. If there is no space between the span and the next word, the line can't break between them. If you really want to have a NBSP there, you can have it with something like `.number::after {content: "\A0";}` in the following snippet.

```css
.number {
  vertical-align: super;
}
.number::after {
  content: "\A0";
}
body {
  width: 11em;
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1</span>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus nec tincidunt erat. <span class="number">2</span>Integer lectus nulla, imperdiet semper pharetra nec, hendrerit ac tortor. Sed nec gravida enim. Quisque quis condimentum odio. <span class="number">3</span>Quisque at sodales arcu. Aenean sapien nibh, faucibus in est id, tempus pellentesque purus. Nulla imperdiet, sem eu pellentesque pretium, justo quam scelerisque neque, vel accumsan dui enim non elit.
```

I didn't find that this behavior is guaranteed, so, to be sure, you can wrap the number with the first word together with an element with `white-space: nowrap;` in CSS. That works even if there is space between the number and the word, like there:

```css
no-br {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.number {
  vertical-align: super;
}
body {
  width: 11em;
}
```

```html
<no-br><span class="number">1</span> Orci</no-br> varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus nec tincidunt erat. <no-br><span class="number">2</span> Integer</no-br> lectus nulla, imperdiet semper pharetra nec, hendrerit ac tortor. Sed nec gravida enim. Quisque quis condimentum odio. <no-br><span class="number">3</span> Quisque</no-br> at sodales arcu. Aenean sapien nibh, faucibus in est id, tempus pellentesque purus. Nulla imperdiet, sem eu pellentesque pretium, justo quam scelerisque neque, vel accumsan dui enim non elit.
```

I set the width of the text in the snippets so that the changes show to me. It may render differently to you, so here is an image of how they are supposed to look:

[image]